# SharePoint List filter web part - remember selection jQuery

Tags: web-part, jquery, filter

I have a SharePoint list filter web part connected to other web parts which filters content based on the our clients names, everything it working great but I have one issues:

When i select a client the web parts update, I open a document from the documentation web part, make my changes and close the document the filter reverts back to the default value, which means I have to re-select the client from the filter

[image]

I'm sure jQuery could probably solve this in some way?

EDIT: I have found this post but does not seem to work for me

[Remember filter value using jquery and cookies](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125333/remember-filter-value-using-jquery-and-cookies)

Do I need to edit the code?

Comment: store the filter state in a cookie or (modern HTML5 browser) Localstorage, upon pageload restore the filterstate

Comment: I have found a post (see my edited posts above) that talks about cookies, I have tried that code but it does not work for me, what do I need to edit in the code to make it work?

Comment: First learn to use cookies/localstorage in a small piece of code, only when you know how it works apply it your application. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp